# Object-oriented way of doing nil checks for associations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have watched Sandi Metz' [nothing is something](http://confreaks.tv/videos/railsconf2015-nothing-is-something) presentation a couple times now.  I realize I do nil checks all over the place in my rails projects, but I don't know how to avoid nil checks and how to do it the object oriented way when it comes to associations.

Consider these associations:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog
end

#app/models/blog.rb
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hash_tag
  has_one :user
end

#app/models/hash_tag.rb
class HashTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :blog
end
```

I grab a user:

```
@user = User.find(1)
```

And I want to find his blog:

```
@user.blog
  => nil
```

It returns `nil` here because this `user` happens to have no associated `blog`, so the following code would break the application if I did something like this for this `user`:

```
@user.blog.title
  => undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass
```

The simple fix is to do it the non-object-oriented way and just do a nil check (but this is what we want to avoid because otherwise nil checks are absolutely everywhere in the application):

```
@user.blog.title if @user.blog
```

Doing nil checks gets more cumbersome and procedural the deeper you go through associations like below:

```
@user = User.find(1)
if @user.blog && @user.blog.hash_tag #checking for nil twice
  @user.blog.hash_tag.tag_name
end
```

What is the object-oriented way of avoiding nil checks for associations?

I am aware of rails' [try method](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try), though Metz did not seem to recommend the `try` method.  Perhaps though when it comes to associations in rails: `try` is the best option?

Comment: **Just a suggestion:** Instead of firing `@user.blog` every time, you can put it in a variable like `@user_blog = @user.blog` and check for it's presence wherever required like: `@user_blog.present?`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is programming design guideline called [The Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)

This is how to apply it to your rails models:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog
    delegate :title, to: :blog, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
    # then you can call user.blog_title
    delegate :tag_name, to: :blog, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
    # follow LoD
end

#app/models/blog.rb
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hash_tag
    delegate :tag_name, to: :hash_tag, allow_nil: true
  has_one :user
end
```

And now you can do this:

```
@user = User.find(1)
@user.blog_title # no error even if there is no associated blog
@user.tag_name # no error even if there is no associatd blog or no associated hash_tag object
```

Please read following link for references:

- http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate
- http://samurails.com/tutorial/rails-delegate-dont-break-the-law-of-demeter/

Comment: Great, you've fixed it by yourself

Answer (score 2):

There is a nifty gem `andand` which I use in cases like this. Normally you would need to write:

```
@user.blog && @user.blog.title
```

`andand` gem implements generic null pattern. `andand` extends Object with a method `andand`, which returns an object it was called on unless it is nil. In case of the nil, NullPatern object is returned to return nil for all method calls using method_missing magic.

```
@user.blog.andand.title
```

It is even more powerful when you need to check more conditions:

```
@user.blog && @user.blog.title && @user.blog.title.capitalize
```

becomes:

```
@user.blog.andand.title.andand.capitalize
```

Comment: I looked into the `andand` gem and it appears the `andand` gem does exactly what the `try` method in rails does already.  `try` came out for rails in version 2.3.2 which was in 2010.  The initial release of the `andand` gem came out in 2008, so I think what happened is `andand` was a great option until `try` came along and was built into rails.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be an options

> I would use: `rescue` method
>   **Caution**: this method catches exceptions and responds accordingly; Don't use this if you need to respond to exceptions differently. I hope you understand

```
@user = User.find(1)
tag_name = @user.blog.hash_tag.tag_name rescue '' # respond with default value
```

Example:

```
2.1.1 :001 > var1 = nil
 => nil 
2.1.1 :002 > my_val = var1.some_method

NoMethodError: undefined method `some_method' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):2
    from /home/shiva/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'

2.1.1 :003 > my_val = var1.some_method rescue ''
 => ""
```

Another option would be `.try` method; http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try

> `.try` is defined in `Rails` so not be available out of `Rails`

```
@person.non_existing_method if @person.respond_to?(:non_existing_method) 
# instead use
@person.try(:non_existing_method) # => returns nil if does not respond_to
```

try returns nil when called on nil regardless of whether it responds to the method:

```
nil.try(:to_i) # => nil, rather than 0
```